# testing elastic search with Symfony 6 under docker and windows 10 return " class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.Map "

Tags: java, php, docker, symfony, elasticsearch

I'm trying to test elastic search using symfony 6 and docker under windows 10 :

```
"friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^6.2",
"php": ">=8.1",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.14",
"symfony": "6.2.*"
```

fos_elastica.yaml :

```
# Read the documentation: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/setup.md
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9209 }
    indexes:
        articles:
            properties:
                type: ~
                name: ~
                slug: ~
                keyword: ~
            persistence:
                driver: orm
                model: App\Entity\Article
                provider: ~
                finder: ~
```

docker-compose.yaml :

```
  # elasticsearch ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

  # elasticsearch server (official image)
  # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: sb-elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.3 # 6.8.4 out
    ports:
      - "9209:9200"
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx1G"
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
      - "http.cors.enabled=true"
      - "http.cors.allow-origin=*"

  # elasticsearch head manager (fork of mobz/elasticsearch-head for elasticsearch 6)
  # /!\ it isn't an official image /!\
  # https://hub.docker.com/r/tobias74/elasticsearch-head
  elasticsearch-head:
    container_name: sb-elasticsearch-head
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    image: tobias74/elasticsearch-head:6
    ports:
      - "9109:9100"
```

When i try : `php bin/console fos:elastica:create` i got this error :

> class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.util.ArrayList and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

any explications please ?